# No animation on RecyclerView item select Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have Navigation Drawer which uses RecyclerView to display header + list of items below. When items are clicked a new fragment is being called.
My problem is that there is no animation on item selection.

This is my main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/navdrawer_listselector"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/navdrawer_listselector"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have set clickable, focusable and focusableInTouchMode to true, also as a background I have set navdrawer_listselector, but it gives no results.

Here is how I have implemented recyclerView item listener :

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            if (child != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                onNavItemSelected(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                drawer.closeDrawers();
                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }
    });
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I know this is old and you've probably found the answer by now, but have you tried making the DrawerLayout in your xml as the root element?

Comment: It couldn't be main element because it was a part of Nav Drawer

Comment: Yes it can, actually, that's how I have my activity set up, and it works fine. Do you want me to post an answer or did you already solve this?

Comment: Thanks, no need to. I managed to do it other way. However, you can paste it for other people if you want.